# Simple hybrid ODE cannot be solved symbolically

Tags: differential-equations

Mathematica solves the following very simple hybrid ODE without any problem:

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0, WhenEvent[x[t] == 2, x[t] -> 0]}, x[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

As soon though as `t` is kept symbolic, Mathematica fails to find the solution:

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0, WhenEvent[x[t] == 2, x[t] -> 0]}, x[t], t]
```

Is this a limitation of Mathematica 12.3.1, or is there a way to specify the problem such that `DSolve` is able to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can help MA a little

```
Clear[y]
y[t_] = DSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0}, x[t], t]
p = t /. Solve[y[t] == 2] // First
z[t_] := y[Mod[t, p]]
```

The steps are

1. Construct general solution without `WhenEven`
2. In the presence of `WhenEven`, the solution is periodic, find period `p`
3. Construct a periodic solution with the help of `Mod`

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you. However, I was wondering about the limitations of DSolve for hybrid ODEs in general. It appears that leaving the independent variable symbolic is not supported at all.

Comment: @MathGaudium I think you are right, and the difficulty is in the treatment of `WhenEvent`. Would be nice to have a more analytic approach.